# Little figurine identification - little grey robot with red eyes

Tags: set-identification, model-identification

[image: little grey robot with red eyes]

I got this little fella from a thrift shop. I just thought it looked cool, but I have no idea which set it originates from. Can anyone help?

Comment: They way it is built makes me think this is a custom creation (MOC).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see from [this search](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=87580&colorID1=86&itemNo2=63864&colorID2=85&itemNo3=4697b&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=86&in=S), of the four sets which contain three of these parts, none include all the parts. This must be someone's own creation (MOC) as identified by [Alex](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/11100/alex).